# Output html tag as text into a div, each array element on separate line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array in javascript file called newElements.

The format likes this:

```
newElements: Array[3]
0: "<p class='Day'>asdasd</p>"
1: "<p class='Day'>123123</p>"
2: "<p class='Day'>Test</p>"
length: 3
```

And I have a div.panel-body.

What I did is

```
for( var i = 0; i < newElements.length; i++) {
new_content += newElements[i];
}
$(".panel-body").text(new_content);
```

It gives me output looks like this:
[image]

However, I want the div format like this:

```
<p class="Day">Some Text</p>
<p class="Day">Another Text</p>
<p class="Session">TEXT</p>
```

Each html tag on a separate line.

**Yes, I know the `<br>` tag, but the question is, if I add `<br>` , the `<br>` tag will be treated as plain text, the output will become like this: `<p class="Day">asdasd</p><br><p class="Day">asds</p>`**

So, could someone give me a nice way to show the output to screen the way I want it. You already have the array I give you.

And if I use html() function, the `<p>` will be treated as real html tag, that's not what I want, I want they be shown.

Comment: have you tried adding a break line "\n" between elements?

Comment: You'll have to add a `<br>` tag between then

Comment: May I ask what font the text in the image is? It looks "professional", and I can never seem to find a good font when I would need one.

Comment: @kukac67   it's font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; for your reference, you can take a look at http://bootswatch.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="hello">

</div>
```

```
<script>
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "<p class='Day'>Hello Xinrui Ma</p>";
mycars[1] = "<p class='Day'>this is the array</p>";
mycars[2] = "<p class='Day'>hopes it fits your need</p>";

 var divHello = $('div.hello')
$.each(mycars, function( index, value ) {
 divHello.append(value);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the code, instead of `.text()`, use `.html()`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4AeR/

My mistake. Since you DO want to show the actual code, add each to its own new element, within the loop. This is the best I can think of:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hb9mC/

Comment: But that will not show the <p class="Day"></p> thing, it only shows the text between html tag

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for( var i = 0; i < newElements.length; i++) {
    $(".panel-body").append(document.createTextNode(newElements[i])).append('<br/>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z3zE/1/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display your code including line breaks. Convert your HTML to entities and add line breaks:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

var newElements = ['<p class="Day">asdasd</p>,<p class="Day">123123</p>,<p class="Day">Test</p>'],
    output = '';

for(var i = 0; i < newElements.length; i++) {
  output += htmlEntities(newElements[i]) + '<br />';
}

$('.panel-body').html(output);
```

http://jsbin.com/mefuhufo/1/edit